# Android: Dont want the ListView to use the complete Drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I'm programming my first little app. In this app i'm using two drawer, one on the right and one on die left side:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#D1933C"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.schnapsidee.app.CustomWebView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/fail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seitenZahl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:width="0dp"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pergament"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
   />
```

I use them like:

```
mDrawerItemLeft = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sidebar_array_left);
    mDrawerItemRight = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sidebar_array_right);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerListLeft = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListRight = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerListLeft.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item_left,
            mDrawerItemLeft));
    mDrawerListRight.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item_right,
            mDrawerItemRight));
    mDrawerListLeft.setOnItemClickListener(new LeftDrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerListRight.setOnItemClickListener(new RightDrawerItemClickListener());
```

My problem is, that i dont want the right Drawer to use the complete screen-height. I just want it to use a part of it like the red part in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdXAf.jpg

Any idea how i can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ever tried: gravity="end"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the Navigation drawer to specifically be a ListView only, you can use any View/ViewGroup for this purpose just set the gravity="end" to make it right navigation drawer.

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pergament"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

Change above code to this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the other attributes of ListView as needed, and change the height to something shorter than 800dp because 800dp is quite long height and will definitely be larger than actual screen height on many devices.

Answer (score 0):

give width **0dp** to both views and add **android:layout_weight="1"** in both views.

Comment: Mhh, that one does not work for me. Is it right to add it in the xml-File? The auto-complete dont know width he just offers me minWidth and he also dont know layout_weight. I can use both without errors but nothing is happens.

Comment: this will work inside LinearLayout, or can you paste full xml coding, so I can take a look why it is not working.

Comment: I editet my post, my complete main_activity.xml is now in it.

Comment: wrap both listviews inside Linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a ListView, use a layout e.g. Linear, Relative and then place the ListView inside that layout. If you place the layout as the last element in your xml, the whole layout becomes the layout of the navigation drawer. You can then position your Listview inside the layout any way you want.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#111"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- Position this list view inside the relative layout the way you  want -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, if you are saying that just by putting the view at last of XML makes it layout for drawer then you are mistaken. Everything is dependent on the gravity attribute.

Comment: The last layout(relative/linear) in this case.

Comment: Yes I am saying that the position of RelativeLayout / LinearLayout doesn't matter. Its about the gravity you give to these.
Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28453748/3485152

Comment: From android docs : The main content view (the FrameLayout above) must be the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.

So, until unless you want the navigation drawer to be below your content, you should keep it as the last element.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you on this point, but this is about whether the view will be completely visible or blocked by other views.
Here, The question is just about changing the height of Right Navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

use in navigation drawer

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

using this, thing you should know ... navigation drawer take height of its content. so it is taking listView,s height .. give height to your listview(as your requirement) then give listView Background "transparent as written below

```
 android:layout_height="as you want"
 android:background="@color/tranparent"
```

to make it under your header then take linear Layout and write navigation drawer,s code after you header .. if you are Relative layout then use `android:layout_below="your header id"` in your navigation drawer.